# Make my voice sound like The Beatles

Tags: music

DISCLAIMER: I know very little about working with audio!!! Okay, so I'm a MASSIVE Beatles fan and am trying to construct a GOOD attempt of their third reunion reunion song from the 90s which is unfinished. It uses John Lennon's unfinished demo usually called "Now and Then", and is poor audio quality.

I've heard of programs that similar to this, but is there a program where I can convert my singing voice and make it sound like Paul McCartney, or even the other Beatles? (With sufficient samples of them, of course!)  Or similar?

What about Adobe VoCo?

Sorry if it's a dumb question, as I am in no way knowledgeable about this topic, but I would love to have this happen. I REALLY need advice with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well…how to say this…

There is no software (that I know of) that can make your voice sound like Paul McCartney's voice. The only way to achieve this is to either;

A. Learn how to sing like Paul McCartney, or;
B. Hire someone who knows how to sing like Paul McCartney.

This forum is really the wrong place to post this question, but I figured it deserved an answer because you seem to be asking with sincerity and are eager to hear from folks who may actually be able to help.

In conclusion, I recommend you start brushing up on your Paul imitation or hire a professional soundalike who can pull it off.

Comment: I would also add that producers and sound engineers tend to find a certain effect that they like for a particular band's vocals and they stick with it. It gives their voice and songs a particular feel. This varies with eras too. I think this would be an important step in recreating Sir Paul's Beatles voice too. I had to re-create Ozzy's vocal effect from Black Sabbath before. It was quite simple in the end. Good luck.